# Network Boot Windows 10 Black Screen

Tags: windows-10, pxe-boot

I am using a Windows Server 2016 machine to host a Tiny PXE Server in order to install Windows 10 from Network Boot into another machine. Both machines are physical and on the same network.

**Main Machine IP:** XXX.YYY.ZZZ.A

**Secondary Machine IP:** XXX.YYY.ZZZ.B

I managed to connect both machines with the help of [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qHHGahJYAvw) tutorial video.
The secondary machine downloaded the necessary files via PXE to start the Windows setup but after the loading screen (image) it gives me a black screen. I waited for over 1 hour but nothing happens.

I tried to change BIOS boot settings but it made no difference.

[image: Microsoft Corporation]

Comment: That doesn't look like Windows 10, though...

Comment: Can you really run Microsofts PXE stack without a special "answer server" these days?
Maybe a log of transferred files could help determine where in the boot process it fails?

I gave up a long time ago and is now a happy user of iPXE and wimboot - which makes this much easier and quicker.

Answer (score 0):

you should probably use Serva instead.

Comment: Tried with Serva but still getting the same error

Comment: OK please add here Serva's Log. BTW your image is not from a Windows net 10 boot.

Answer (score -1):

That error usually happen when the PXE can't load the full NIC driver inside the OS or a missing drivers completely.

Try on another machine platform, or add the correct NIC driver .inf inside the correct folder to slipstream the driver correctly for the target computer. See that [page](http://mistyrebootfiles.altervista.org/documents/TinyPXEServer/files/ris.htm#drivers) for a small howto (but the page seem old)